# How to add a legend to a `SmoothDensityHistogram`?

Tags: plotting, legending

Is there a way to add a legend to a [`SmoothDensityHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html?view=all)?

`DensityHistogram` accepts the `ChartLegends` option. Other plots accept the `PlotLegends`. However, the `SmoothDensityHistogram` does not accept any of them. Is there another solution?

Comment: a workaround: use `DensityPlot[
 PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]`?

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** A slightly more direct approach to construct the bar legend using `"PDFValues"` property of data distribution object returned by `SmoothKernelDistribution`:

```
Legended[SmoothDensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {0, Max @ skd["PDFValues"]}}]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

A workaround: (1) Use the pdf of the `SmoothKernelDistribution` of `data` (using the same bandwidth and kernel specs as in your `SmoothDensityHistogram`) in a `DensityPlot` with the option `PlotLegends` and (2) extract the legend (the second part) from the output and add it to your `SmoothDensityHistogram`  it using `Legended`.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];

legend = DensityPlot[Evaluate@PDF[skd, {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic][[2]];

Legended[SmoothDensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], legend]
```

[image]

Comment: At that point why not just use `NMaximize` on the `SmoothKernelDistribution` and create the `BarLegend` explicitly?

Comment: @b3m2a1, I updated with a more direct way to get the peak value of pdf.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that property but I expect I will find myself using it

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234]

data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];

peak = MaxValue[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], {x, y}], {x, y}];

Legended[
 SmoothDensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"],
 BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, peak}}]]
```

[image]