# Computing density of particles and distances from microscopic images

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I am analysing microscopic particles images of the kind shown below, and primarily I am interested in learning whether in Mathematica one can extract structural properties of the particles using the built-in image analysis tools.

More precisely,

- is it for instance possible to compute the nearest-neighbour distance distribution?
- Or more importantly, measuring the density of particles from the image? (that is, number of particles per area when binning the image).

*I admit there might be similar questions previously asked but I could not pinpoint one that tackled such problem, so any help would be much appreciated.*

Image example ([source](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/352nk3c6sz/2)):

[image]

---

The kind of analysis I have learned so far is to use the ridge lines separating the particles in order to detect them and find their centres of mass based on the point of maximum distance to a ridge line (per particle). Here's an example

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUnvs.jpg"]
ridgelines = RidgeFilter[-img, 4];
distanceRidges = 
 DistanceTransform@
  ColorNegate@
   MorphologicalBinarize[
    ridgelines] (*distance transform image based on the ridge filter*)
\
distMaximum = 
 MaxDetect[distanceRidges, 
  4] (*find centre of masses using max ridge dists*)
```

which yields:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you do `dots = SelectComponents[Pruning[Thinning@distMaximum], #Count == 1 &]` you can get those blobs as entirely single dots. Then `PixelValuePositions[dots,1]` will get you their centers. From there you can do `DistanceMatrix` and other such things like `Nearest` etc.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203517/creating-graph-out-of-particles-images), with great answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going in the right direction. You could also attempt a segmentation from your ridge filtering and extract the centroids of the components. This is a bit sensitive to the `"MinimumSaliency"` value so it needs some manual intervention:

```
wsh = WatershedComponents[ridgelines, Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 0.2}];
wsh // Colorize
centroids = Values[Select[ComponentMeasurements[wsh, "Centroid"], #[[1]] > 1 &]];
```

[image: segmentation]

The advantage of `ComponentMeasurements` is you can get the `"Area"` and `"EquivalentDiskRadius"` if those things interest you too.

You can use the centroids and compute a `DistanceMatrix`:

```
dmtx = DistanceMatrix[centroids];
```

... or create a `Nearest` function and get the distance to the closest component centroid:

```
nf = Nearest[centroids];
BoxWhiskerChart[
 EuclideanDistance[#, Last[nf[#, 2]]] & /@ centroids
]
```

[image: distances]

So the median distance between centroids of the cells is about 42 pixels.

---

Here's how you could get a density map based on the dots method I proposed in the question comments, but you could alternatively use the centroids I calculated above in place of `positions`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUnvs.jpg"];
ridgelines = RidgeFilter[-img, 4];
distanceRidges = 
 DistanceTransform@
  ColorNegate@
   MorphologicalBinarize[
    ridgelines];

distMaximum = MaxDetect[distanceRidges, 4];
dots = SelectComponents[Pruning[Thinning@distMaximum], #Count == 1 &];
positions = PixelValuePositions[dots, 1];
Blend[{
  Image[SmoothDensityHistogram[positions, 60, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]],
  img}, .5]
```

Note that the density is fairly uniform and that I needed to manually provide the width as the automatic width was inadequate and didn't capture the lower density near the holes.

[image: cell density]

Comment: You may want to consider `DeleteSmallComponents` too if there are small fragments that are biasing the result down.

Comment: Hi! Many thanks, this has been really instructive, I did not know yet `ComponentMeasurements` could be used in such ways! If I may ask, regarding the density question (count of particle per area of bin), the attempt is to find out locally in the image where there are a higher density of particles (intuitively, like a heat-map that shows this fluctuation). Do you happen to have some ideas as to how we could tackle this? thanks again!

Comment: @CuriousBadger I added a density map. It performs okay-ish but needs manual adjustment of the kernel width for the holes to show up as low-density patches. The holes could be highlighted by other means however, as they are quite dark regions compared to the cells.

Comment: This is remarkably efficient! Thank you flinty! Does SmoothDensityHistogram allow to extract the density profile in a numerical fashion? (i.e. how density changes as a function of x-axis for instance)

Comment: @CuriousBadger you should look into `SmoothKernelDistribution` for that purpose.

Comment: Thx, the documentation seems to show a lot of properties for that function, I will look into it! If I may ask 2 last questions: 1) can we add a barlegend to our smoothdensityhistogram that shows the mapping between numbers and colors? 2) back to the density again, can we use our own counting (like in `dots`) of the particles in rectangular bins of the transformed image (detected components) in order to estimate the density numerically? I understand if you don't have time to address these questions, no worries at all, your patience is much appreciated and answers have been already most helpful.

Comment: For 1), yes see this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211787/how-to-add-a-legend-to-a-smoothdensityhistogram and for 2) There's BinCounts, but also you could use DensityHistogram which bins in boxes and isn't smooth

Comment: Sry to write again. Unfortunately I'm hitting a wall with my approaches to compute the density of particles per bin. To show the problem, here's e.g. one idea: `Blend[{Image[
   DensityHistogram[centroids, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
    Frame -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]], img}, .5]` then also doing the hist separately to read off the numbers (hovering cursor over bins): `DensityHistogram[centroids, ColorFunction -> Hue]`, the number of detected particles per bin are completely off. Also tried using `wsh = WatershedComponents[ridgelines, distMaximum, 
   Method -> "Basins"];` to no avail.

Comment: @CuriousBadger you should try out the techniques in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203540/72682) first. The centroids from the above are probably not the best quality as seen in `HighlightImage[img, centroids]`. There are centroids appearing in the gaps where they probably shouldn't be, leading to a higher density there.

Comment: Dear flinty, hi again! I had a question related to our post here: similar to getting the distances between the centroids, would it be also feasible to compute the shortest surface-surface distances between the detected components? ultimately, the aim is to have a rough estimation of the histogram of separations between the particles.